# How to find value of $x?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

$A = x^{1/4} $

$B = x^{1/6}$

And $A^2 = 4B$

Find values of $x$ .

Can I get a hint on how to solve this ?

Comment: Do you mean $x^{1/4}$ and $x^{1/6}$? If so try putting $y=x^{1/6}$. Now what does $A^2=4B$ become in terms of $y$?

Comment: x= 0 is one obvious solution.

Comment: Personally, I would try using some math.

Answer (score 0):

According to given equation:

$$A^2=4B$$

Put the value of $A$ and $B$ in above equation, then:
$$(x^{1/4})^2=4(x^{1/6})$$

$$(x^{1/2})=4(x^{1/6})$$

Take square both sides, then:
$$x=16(x^{1/3})$$

$$(x^{2/3})\times (x^{1/3})=16(x^{1/3})$$

$$(x^{2/3})=16$$

Take square root both sides, then:
$$(x^{1/3})=4$$

Take cube both sides, then:
$$x=4\times4\times4=64$$

Comment: Be careful:  You lost a solution when you divided by $x^{1/3}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, please, clarify, little bit more, I did not get you?

Comment: Since division by zero is undefined, you must check that $x^{1/3} \neq 0$  before you divide by it.  In fact, it can equal zero, which is the solution you lost when you divided by $x^{1/3}$.   You can write the equation in the form $16x^{1/3} - x = 0$, then factor.

Answer (score 0):

We are given the values
\begin{align*}
A & = x^{1/4}\\
B & = x^{1/6}
\end{align*}
and asked to solve the equation 
$$A^2 = 4B$$
Substituting $(x^{1/4})^2 = x^{1/2}$ for $A^2$ and $x^{1/6}$ for $B$ in the equation $A^2 = 4B$ yields
$$x^{1/2} = 4x^{1/6}$$
If we make the substitution $u = x^{1/6}$, we obtain
$$u^3 = 4u$$
which can be solved by subtracting $4u$ from each side of the equation, then factoring.  Finally, note that $u = x^{1/6}$ denotes the principal (non-negative) real root of $x$, so $u \geq 0$.